# getActionBar() returns null in PreferenceActivity (AppCompat-v7 21)

Tags: android, preferenceactivity

I have implemented DoneBar (two buttons in actionbar) in `PreferenceActivity` as provided in v20 sdk samples, but after updating SDK and AppCompat to version 21 my app crashes at

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setDisplayOptions(int, int)' on a null object reference`

That is because `getActionBar()` returns null. And There is no `getSupportActionBar()` as in `ActionBarActivity`.

So my question is how to get that actionbar object in `PreferenceActivity` so I could apply custom view on it?

SOLVED

After some research I managed to solve this problem by using `PreferenceFragment` with `ActionBarActivity` so I could call `getSupportActionBar()`

Comment: Hey, would it be possible that you create an answer with the solution code in it? I currently have the same issue and cannot really find out what the problem is.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

as xXx requested I am providing example how I done:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Display the fragment as the main content.
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment())
                .commit();

        // use action bar here
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    }

    public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle paramBundle) {
            super.onCreate(paramBundle);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_settings);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can I use this with header xml files, which are used in `PreferenceActivity` in `onBuildHeaders()`?

Comment: And what theme did you use?

Comment: Note that you can use non-support PreferenceFragment with ActionBarActivity on API > 11, just use getFragmentManager() to add it.Worked for me. For earlier versions of Android I guess the only way is to use some backported PreferenceFragment from github.

Comment: When a nested "PreferenceScreen" is displayed, the action bar is removed. Is there any solution that works with appcompat-v7 21?

Answer (score 18):

I managed to fix this issue by specifying custom theme for my settings activity,

```
<style name="SettingsTheme" parent="style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
</style>
```

and : `android:theme="@style/SettingsTheme"` in manifest for activity

actionbar is again showing on KITKAT and LOLIPOP and (have not tested it) back to api v11. I tested it and it works (with no actionbar as expected) on api 10.

From debugging on lolipop, `FEATURE_NO_TITLE` was being set in `PhoneWindow.java:3243` :

```
   if (a.getBoolean(R.styleable.Window_windowNoTitle, false)) {
        requestFeature(FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

which removes `FEATURE_ACTION_BAR`

[edit]

but this action bar is not from material theme, so still its not perfect

[edit2]

I gave up with Headers, now I am using PreferenceFragment backport from github. Now all my actionbars are the same after upgrade to appcompact 21.

Comment: Which is correct. Do not use `Theme.AppCompat` unless your Activity extends `ActionBarActivity`.

Comment: @ChrisBanes ok, so if I want actionbar in my preferences then I should use ActionBarActivity with PreferenceFragment. ActionBar in preferenceActivity is deprecetad and since 21 non supported? can you suggest how to implement headers with PreferenceFragment in ActionBarActivity? I currently use loadHeadersFromResource.

Comment: I don't understand why this correct answer was down voted (so I up voted for one)

Answer (score 7):

#### `getActionBar()` returns null in API 5.0 when i use `Activity` or `FragmentActivity`.

I solved this extendig to `ActionBarActivity`

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
```

You must use `getSupportActionBar()` when you are using `ActionBarActivity` (`appcompat-v7`).

Answer (score 1):

Issue resolved by doing this, your styles xml should looks like this.

**res/values/style.xml**

```
<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>
```

**res/values-v11/style.xml**

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light"> 
        <!-- API 11 theme customizations can go here. -->
    </style>
```

**res/values-v14/style.xml**

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light"> 
        <!-- API 11 theme customizations can go here. -->
    </style>
```