# Cant add action bar to preference activity

Tags: android, android-actionbar, preferenceactivity

I want to add customized action bar in my Filter Activity which is a PreferenceActivity.

Can I use addPreferencesFromResource() method with ActionBarActivity ???

Every thing is working fine as my java file and xml file is correct. But there is no action bar, and when i attempt to call *getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.xyz);* there is a crash.
Please help me out.

here is my java code of the preference screen

```
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;

public class Filter extends PreferenceActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.filter_screen);
        Drawable d=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.abfilter);
        getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(d);

    }
}
```

here is the logcat

```
11-22 16:18:13.377    7460-7460/com.example.avinash.swipetab D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
11-22 16:18:13.481    7460-7460/com.example.avinash.swipetab W/ActivityThread﹕ Application com.example.avinash.swipetab is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
11-22 16:18:13.487    7460-7460/com.example.avinash.swipetab I/System.out﹕ Sending WAIT chunk
11-22 16:18:13.494    7460-7468/com.example.avinash.swipetab I/dalvikvm﹕ Debugger is active
11-22 16:18:13.687    7460-7460/com.example.avinash.swipetab I/System.out﹕ Debugger has connected
11-22 16:18:13.688    7460-7460/com.example.avinash.swipetab I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
11-22 16:18:13.888    7460-7460/com.example.avinash.swipetab I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
11-22 16:18:14.088    7460-7460/com.example.avinash.swipetab I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
11-22 16:18:14.289    7460-7460/com.example.avinash.swipetab I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
11-22 16:18:14.489    7460-7460/com.example.avinash.swipetab I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
11-22 16:18:14.689    7460-7460/com.example.avinash.swipetab I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
11-22 16:18:14.889    7460-7460/com.example.avinash.swipetab I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
11-22 16:18:15.090    7460-7460/com.example.avinash.swipetab I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
11-22 16:18:15.290    7460-7460/com.example.avinash.swipetab I/System.out﹕ debugger has settled (1413)
11-22 16:18:15.713    7460-7460/com.example.avinash.swipetab I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onNestedScrollAccepted, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onNestedScrollAccepted
11-22 16:18:15.713    7460-7460/com.example.avinash.swipetab W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11365: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onNestedScrollAccepted (Landroid/view/View;Landroid/view/View;I)V
11-22 16:18:15.713    7460-7460/com.example.avinash.swipetab D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
11-22 16:18:15.714    7460-7460/com.example.avinash.swipetab I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onStopNestedScroll, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onStopNestedScroll
11-22 16:18:15.714    7460-7460/com.example.avinash.swipetab W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11371: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onStopNestedScroll (Landroid/view/View;)V
11-22 16:18:15.714    7460-7460/com.example.avinash.swipetab D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
11-22 16:18:15.716    7460-7460/com.example.avinash.swipetab I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.stopNestedScroll, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.setHideOnContentScrollEnabled
11-22 16:18:15.716    7460-7460/com.example.avinash.swipetab W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 9059: Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/ActionBarOverlayLayout;.stopNestedScroll ()V
11-22 16:18:15.716    7460-7460/com.example.avinash.swipetab D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000e
11-22 16:18:15.734    7460-7460/com.example.avinash.swipetab I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
11-22 16:18:15.734    7460-7460/com.example.avinash.swipetab W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 367: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
11-22 16:18:15.734    7460-7460/com.example.avinash.swipetab D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
11-22 16:18:15.736    7460-7460/com.example.avinash.swipetab I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
11-22 16:18:15.736    7460-7460/com.example.avinash.swipetab W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 389: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
11-22 16:18:15.736    7460-7460/com.example.avinash.swipetab D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
11-22 16:18:15.886    7460-7460/com.example.avinash.swipetab D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 177K, 10% free 3028K/3328K, paused 10ms, total 10ms
11-22 16:18:15.887    7460-7460/com.example.avinash.swipetab I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 3.681MB for 635812-byte allocation
11-22 16:18:15.900    7460-7473/com.example.avinash.swipetab D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 8K, 8% free 3640K/3952K, paused 8ms, total 8ms
11-22 16:18:16.124    7460-7460/com.example.avinash.swipetab D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 49K, 6% free 4040K/4272K, paused 10ms, total 10ms
11-22 16:18:16.155    7460-7460/com.example.avinash.swipetab D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 323K, 13% free 3897K/4448K, paused 8ms, total 8ms
11-22 16:18:16.220    7460-7460/com.example.avinash.swipetab D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 6% free 4220K/4448K, paused 9ms, total 9ms
11-22 16:18:16.256    7460-7460/com.example.avinash.swipetab D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 318K, 12% free 4227K/4768K, paused 9ms, total 9ms
11-22 16:18:16.297    7460-7460/com.example.avinash.swipetab D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 5% free 4550K/4768K, paused 9ms, total 9ms
11-22 16:18:16.375    7460-7460/com.example.avinash.swipetab D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 4% free 4887K/5088K, paused 9ms, total 9ms
11-22 16:18:16.436    7460-7460/com.example.avinash.swipetab D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 4% free 5217K/5408K, paused 9ms, total 9ms
11-22 16:18:16.584    7460-7460/com.example.avinash.swipetab D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 3% free 5889K/6048K, paused 9ms, total 9ms
11-22 16:18:16.641    7460-7460/com.example.avinash.swipetab E/﹕ appName=com.example.avinash.swipetab, acAppName=/system/bin/surfaceflinger
11-22 16:18:16.641    7460-7460/com.example.avinash.swipetab E/﹕ 0
11-22 16:18:16.645    7460-7460/com.example.avinash.swipetab I/MaliEGL﹕ [Mali]window_type=1, is_framebuffer=0, errnum = 0
11-22 16:18:16.645    7460-7460/com.example.avinash.swipetab I/MaliEGL﹕ [Mali]surface->num_buffers=4, surface->num_frames=3, win_min_undequeued=1
11-22 16:18:16.645    7460-7460/com.example.avinash.swipetab I/MaliEGL﹕ [Mali]max_allowed_dequeued_buffers=3
11-22 16:18:16.649    7460-7460/com.example.avinash.swipetab D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
11-22 16:18:17.386    7460-7460/com.example.avinash.swipetab D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 173K, 5% free 6246K/6544K, paused 10ms, total 10ms
11-22 16:18:17.471    7460-7460/com.example.avinash.swipetab D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 32K, 5% free 6989K/7312K, paused 9ms, total 9ms
11-22 16:18:17.572    7460-7460/com.example.avinash.swipetab I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 94 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-22 16:18:21.307    7460-7460/com.example.avinash.swipetab D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 94K, 3% free 8280K/8500K, paused 12ms, total 12ms
11-22 16:18:21.451    7460-7460/com.example.avinash.swipetab D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
11-22 16:18:21.451    7460-7460/com.example.avinash.swipetab W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41541ba8)
11-22 16:18:21.467    7460-7460/com.example.avinash.swipetab E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.avinash.swipetab, PID: 7460
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.avinash.swipetab/com.example.avinash.swipetab.Filter}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.avinash.swipetab.Filter.onCreate(Filter.java:17)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ActionBarPreferenceActivity

Comment: https://github.com/srenner/billminder-android/tree/master/src/com/srenner/billminder

Comment: https://github.com/kolavar/android-support-v4-preferencefragment

Comment: I had the same problem. Look at my solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26439139/getactionbar-returns-null-in-preferenceactivity-appcompat-v7-21/26460937#26460937

Comment: @Ogix getting an error in line getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment()).commit();

Comment: What error? Your class should extend `ActionBarActivity` as in my example.

Comment: that i have done, m getting the following message
replace (int, androidsupportv4.app.Fragment) in FragmentTransaction cannot be applied to (int, <my class name>)

Comment: possible duplicate of [No ActionBar in PreferenceActivity after upgrade to Support Library v21](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26509180/no-actionbar-in-preferenceactivity-after-upgrade-to-support-library-v21)