# I am extending some important class (not ListActivity ) , and want to use ActionBar without extending ActionBarActivity / AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, android-actionbar

getSupportActionBar() is giving error because class not extended from ActionBarActivity / AppCompatActivity  .

I have tried with getActionBar() but not working .

Is it possible to get Action Bar without extending ActionBarActivity / AppCompatActivity ?

My code :-
Here is my Class

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity implements CallBackListener {
```

And here is the code where i need to use getSupportActionBar() method , but it is giving error :-

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    getSupportActionBar().getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.menu_icon)
            .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    toggle();
                }
            });
```

Comment: To which "important class" are you referring?

Comment: Which class does `BaseActivity` extend?

Comment: com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.app.SlidingFragmentActivity

Comment: That's a descendant of a regular Activity, so `getActionBar()` will work, but only down to API 11. What specific problems are you having?

Comment: I tried using getActionBar() but getting NullPointerException             Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)' on a null object reference                                                           and i am using API 21 .

Comment: Which API level are you running under? Are you using a `NoActionBar` theme?

Comment: I am running under API level 21  . And i am not using NoActionBar theme .

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26449687). Never mind the AppCompat. Just check those attributes in your current theme.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer to your question is **NO** .

Simply because the `getActionBar()` and `getSupportActionBar()` are part of `AppCompatActivity` and earlier classes. Do have a look at the [Developer reference](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html) to understand better.